# Python csv file - Open a csv file and take all info from 2 columns, get unique values and then remove some replies(without Pandas)

Tags: python, csv

I have created a csv file with 5 columns

```
Machines | VM | Status | Node | Resolve
```

I want to take all values under Node and Resolve, find the unique values and then remove certain responses(There are some "none" and "record" there which I don't need).

What is the best way to do this?

I was trying to take 1 column at a time and then putting it in sets which did work but is there a quicker way? From the set I was then trying to take away the values I didn't need but realised I was ending up with some values have \n at the end.

Usually I use Pandas which I love to us but I am unable to use this on the machine I am working on at the moment.

```
unique3=[]

with open("machines.csv", "r") as file:
    mach = file.readlines()
    
     for c in mach:
        split_lines = c.split(",")[3]
        unique3.append(split_lines)
       
unique4=[]

with open("machines.csv", "r") as file2:
    mach2 = file2.readlines()

    for c in mach2:
        split_lines2 = c.split(",")[4]
        unique4.append(split_lines2)

uniqueunique = (set(unique4 + unique3))
```

Any help greatly appreciated, I know this is probably straight forward but I struggle with lists and strings

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to add a few example rows and show what the expected output would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import csv

with open("machines.csv", "r") as f:
    rdr = csv.reader(f)
    next(rdr) # skip header if any, otherwise - remove this line
    *_, node, resolve = zip(*rdr)
    unique = set(node).union(set(resolve))
    print(unique)
```

Then you can remove unwanted values

Comment: additional) `set(node).union(set(resolve))` can be replaced as `set(node) | set(union)` [ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: @minolee, it's a matter of preference to use `set(node).union(set(resolve))` vs `set(node) | set(resolve)`

Comment: sure, my comment was just for additional information :) I didn't mean to say your answer was wrong. (sorry for my bad English)